# Nginx with php-fpm in a docker container is not loggin php errors

Tags: php, docker, nginx

I'm using `docker` for setting up a `nginx` and `php-fpm` server. And I have the next problem, when I have an error in `php` nginx does not log the error anywhere.

I have this in my project conf.

**project.conf**

```
error_log /LOGS/simple_error.log debug;
access_log /LOGS/custom_access.log;
```

Inside the access file, I can see this lanes. That means I have a 500 status error, and I cannot see why.

Both of project error log, nginx error log are completely empty and I cannot see why.

> 172.17.0.1 - - [05/Apr/2019:11:51:31 +0000] "POST /user/create/ HTTP/1.1" 500 5 "-" "PostmanRuntime/7.6.1"
>
> 172.17.0.1 - - [05/Apr/2019:11:52:20 +0000] "POST /user/create/ HTTP/1.1" 200 58 "-" "PostmanRuntime/7.6.1"

I added this in the www.conf inside php configuration folder, and I still don't have error log from php.

**www.conf**

```
php_flag[display_errors] = on
php_admin_value[error_log] = /var/log/fpm-php.www.log
php_admin_flag[log_errors] = on
```

Inside `/var/log/` directory there are two directories but there is not `php-fpm` log I'm looking for`.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: i guess 'the why' would be available in server logs...

Comment: You're bashed into the container?

Comment: I have the `Logs` directory shared between container and host.

Comment: @rajesh Why doesn't nginx write error log?

Comment: `PHP` errors would be logged with `php-fpm` as `nginx` is proxying the request to `php-fpm`. No errors happened in `nginx` so nothing to report.

Comment: I updated the question, and I still do not have any errors.